# WebView opens default browser when application starting

Tags: android, webview

My problem isn't when i click the link. It goes when application starting.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser);

        WebView wvBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        wvBrowser.loadUrl("http://yusufalibozkir.com");
    }
```

And, xml:

```
<WebView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wvBrowser"
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://yusufalibozkir.com` issues an `HTTP 301` redirect response. `WebView` treats redirects in the same way it treats link clicks, by opening the default Web browser. Use a `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to catch this occurrence and load the resulting URL back in the `WebView`, or use a URL that does not issue a redirect in the first place.

Comment: @YusufAli: I have no idea what "the link" is, so I cannot comment on that. You are welcome to use **`curl`** or other tools to verify my claim that your URL issues an `HTTP 301` redirect.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose I understand.. The reason is my url redirect?